# Is the Laos/China border at Boten/Mohan open 24 hours?

Tags: china, borders, laos, land-borders, opening-hours

Tomorrow I'll be hitchhiking just a couple of hundred kilometres in China to cross the border into Laos on the last day of my Chinese visa.

Is there any chance that I could arrive too late if I have bad luck, or is the border crossing open around the clock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO.**

It closes at **9.30pm** on the Chinese side, Mohan.

It closes at **8.30pm** on the Lao side, Boten.

(Laos and China run in different time zones one hour apart.)

Source: I crossed this border on foot tonight from China to Laos and asked the immigration officer on the Chinese side whether the crossing is open all night.

Comment: So if I have that right, it closes at the same actual time on both sides, at 13.30 UTC?

Comment: Actually I asked on the Chinese side as I was exiting and extrapolated the rest. I ran into some issues with currencies and passport photos on the Lao side and wasn't sure what the time difference was yet at that point. But while dealing with those issues the visa on arrival guy said I was good to go, got on his motorbike, and went home. So I believe I extrapolated correctly but a second opinion wouldn't hurt! (-: